# DBHelper can not resolve to variable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am Developing a simple registration login system.In each Class there are many same errors of each DbHelper occurrence.The Error is DBHelper can not resolve to variable.My resource files are error free.I am Posting One of Class code here

Here is my code

```
package my.DataBase;

import my.DataBase.R;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.ContentValues;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.AdapterView;

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Spinner;

import android.widget.Toast;


public class Registration extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener


{
 // Variable Declaration should be in onCreate()
 private Button mSubmit;
 private Button mCancel;

 private EditText mFname;
 private EditText mLname;
 private EditText mUsername;
 private EditText mPassword;
 private EditText mEmail;
 private Spinner mGender;
 private String Gen;

 protected DBHelper DB = new DBHelper(Registration.this); 

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.register);

  //Assignment of UI fields to the variables
  mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
  mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

  mCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
  mCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

  mFname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.efname);
  mLname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.elname);

  mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reuname);
  mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.repass);
  mEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eemail);


  mGender = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

  // Spinner method to read the on selected value
  ArrayAdapter<State> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<State>(this,
               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new State[] { 
            new State("Male"), 
            new State("Female")});
  mGender.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
  mGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); 
 }



 public void onClick(View v) 
 {

  switch(v.getId()){

  case R.id.cancel:
   Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginActivity.class);
   startActivity(i);
   //finish();
   break;

  case R.id.submit:


   String fname = mFname.getText().toString();
   String lname = mLname.getText().toString();

   String uname = mUsername.getText().toString();
   String pass = mPassword.getText().toString();
   String email = mEmail.getText().toString();


   boolean invalid = false;

   if(fname.equals(""))
   {
    invalid = true;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your Firstname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   else

   if(lname.equals(""))
   {
    invalid = true;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Lastname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   else

    if(uname.equals(""))
    {
     invalid = true;
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else


      if(pass.equals(""))
     {
      invalid = true;
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
     else 
      if(email.equals(""))
   {
    invalid = true;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Email ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
     else
      if(invalid == false)
      {
       addEntry(fname, lname, Gen, uname, pass, email);
       Intent i_register = new Intent(Registration.this, LoginActivity.class);
       startActivity(i_register);
       //finish();
      }

      break;
      }
    }





 public void onDestroy()
 {
  super.onDestroy();
  DB.close();
 }



 private void addEntry(String fname, String lname, String Gen, String uname, String pass, String email) 
 {

  SQLiteDatabase db = DB.getWritableDatabase();

  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put("firstname", fname);
  values.put("lastname", lname);
  values.put("gender", Gen);
  values.put("username", uname);
  values.put("password", pass);
  values.put("email", email);

  try
  {
   db.insert(DBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your details submitted Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }


  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
     {
      // Get the currently selected State object from the spinner
      State st = (State)mGender.getSelectedItem();

      // Show it via a toast
      toastState( "onItemSelected", st );
     } 


 public void toastState(String name, State st) 
 {
  if ( st != null )
     {
   Gen = st.name;
  //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Gen, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }

 }


 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In here :

```
protected DBHelper DB = new DBHelper(Registration.this);
```

move initialization of DB inside an method instead of initializing at class level as :

```
protected DBHelper DB;  //<<< declare here
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.register);

  DB = new DBHelper(Registration.this);  //<<<< initialize here..
   .....
```